# Deprecated: Function session_is_registered() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\student-information-system\index.php on line 3

Tags: php

Error showing in wamp server php v5.3 not showing in php v 5.2 can i fix this problem in php v5.3 This the the php file.Error in line 3

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_is_registered(username)) {
    header("location:admin.php");
}
```

?>

Comment: -1 for not reading the manual or googling this

Comment: Can you please fix this error

Comment: kinda useless to -1 a new user - let's vote to close the question

Comment: I've always wondered: if the questioner is unable to read the manual, then how do they expect to be able to read any answers posted here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
       //do stuff
    }
```